# Django not accepting JSON data from the client

Tags: python, json, django, afnetworking

Question: recJSON = json.loads(request.body) is throwing Exception.

```
def addPatient(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Convert JSON to python objects and
        # store into the DB
        print request.encoding
        #body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-16')
        #try:
        recJSON = json.loads(request.body)
        #except ValueError:
        #  print "%s",ValueError
        print "%s",request.body

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(request.body),content_type="application/json")
```

Exception:

```
 recJSON = json.loads(request.body)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 505, in loads
 return _default_decoder.decode(s)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
  obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
 return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/scanner.py", line 127, in scan_once
 return _scan_once(string, idx)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/scanner.py", line 118, in _scan_once
 raise JSONDecodeError(errmsg, string, idx)
 JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

From Client:

Using AFNetworking and sending the request using below POST:

```
 // Create JSON data
 NSMutableDictionary* sendID = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init ];
 [sendID setObject:senderID forKey:@"SenderID"];

 NSMutableDictionary* sendDispName = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init ];
 [sendDispName setObject:displayName forKey:@"SenderDispName"];

 NSMutableDictionary* sendMessage = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init ];
 [sendMessage setObject:text forKey:@"Message"];

 NSMutableDictionary* sendDate = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init ];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[sendDate setObject:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] forKey:@"SendDate"];


 NSMutableArray* dataToSend = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [dataToSend addObject:sendID];
 [dataToSend addObject:sendDispName];
 [dataToSend addObject:sendMessage];
 [dataToSend addObject:sendDate];

 NSData* jSenderData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataToSend options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

 NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jSenderData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

 [_manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"TOKEN" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CSRFTOKEN"];
 [_manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json"   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


[_manager POST:@"addPatient/" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formdata)
 { [formdata appendPartWithHeaders:nil body:jSenderData];}
       success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
```

I read that UTF-8 encoding has issue with json.dumps(request.body) which was fixed in Python 3.0
http://bugs.python.org/issue11489

Is it same issue I am facing. This is my first project with Django and Python so any extra information will be  greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: could you show us the `request.body`

Comment: Can you please post an example of you JSON data?

Comment: You don't seem to be posting JSON at all, so it's not clear why you are trying to decode it as such. I don't know much Objective-C but it does look like you are posting normal multipart/form-data.

Comment: To me it looks like you are posting a multipart form in which case, the data would end up somewhere in [`request.POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST). Is the JSON wrapped inside the form, because I also don't see any JSON in the client side code?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I updated my post. In iOS I am using a function to check if my data is JSONable     


   if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dataToSend])
    {
        NSLog(@"Yes It can be\r\n");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"NO it cannot");
    }
to confirm my data is JSONable.

Comment: @dhke May be you are right. Can you please let me know where should I  look. I tried request.POST also but no success.

Comment: @LittleQ my request.body looks like below:

 --Boundary+0F6D42D801782A94

[{"SenderID":"XXXX"},{"SenderDispName":"XXXXX YYYYYY"},{"Message":"hi"},{"SendDate":""}]
--Boundary+0F6D42D801782A94--

Comment: You're POST-ing a [multipart form](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html), not JSON. (You can tell, because the POST body doesn't look like JSON). Use `AFJSONRequestSerializer` and just pass  `dataToSend` as the `parameters` parameter.

Comment: Also, don't create `NSDateFormatter` instances like that every time—it's a very expensive operation. Instead, keep a cached reference and use that instead.

Comment: @mattt Thank you for response. I was doing exactly what you asked not to do. After converting dataToSend and AFJSONRequestSerializer it worked.

So when do we use multipart form? I read it and it seems if we have larger datapayload then we should use multipart form. I know in my case, payload wasnt that large but say I have large JSON, still I pass the data in Parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two things I was doing wrong here.

1. In my code, I was creating payload to be send as a dictionary and I was using AFJSONRequestSerializer and later NSJSONSerialization to get NSData (passed to request structure). So in other words I was trying to create JSON of JSON data.

   ```
    NSData* jSenderData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataToSend options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jSenderData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

   [_manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"TOKEN" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CSRFTOKEN"];
   [_manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json"   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


   [_manager POST:@"addPatient/" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formdata)
   ```

   { [formdata appendPartWithHeaders:nil body:jSenderData];}
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
2. Second thing I was going was on the use of multi-part form request. I was trying to send JSON data as a body of multi-part form. This was not getting correctly interpreted at the server.

Thank you to the community for your help .